# file_get_contents() Google Text to Speech audio file non-english/latin characters

Tags: php, api, text-to-speech, file-get-contents

I searched through existing threads but couldn't find any solutions.. here's my question.

I'm using google's text to speech to download mp3 files. The function works great for english characters.. and languages using english characters. Unfortunately, for Russian (or any non-latin characters) my script generates the correct url, but doesnt download any content (but it does download a 0kb file.. empty)

```
file_put_contents($filepath,file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=".$lang."&q=".rawurlencode($transtext).""));
```

So a sample french word (phone) `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone`

When I go to the page manually, and download the file, everything works.. but not with the `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the input encoding parameter (`ie=UTF-8`) and encode the translation text accordingly.

For example, the following PHP snippet can be used to download the audio file for "téléphone" (in French) from the Google TTS service. Notice it does not work properly without the input encoding parameter.

```
$transtext = "t\xe9l\xe9phone"; // ISO-8859-1 string to be encoded in UTF-8
$base_url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?';
$qs = http_build_query(array(
    'tl' => 'fr',
    'ie' => 'UTF-8',
    'q' => utf8_encode($transtext)
));
$contents = file_get_contents($base_url . $qs);
```

Comment: Hi, when i put "ie=UT8" to google translate's URL, it works fine, thank you.

Comment: That's why the query string $qs is appended to the $base_url in the last line. $qs is equal to 'tl=fr&ie=UTF-8&q='... (and the encoded $transtext)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very poor way to download a file through HTTP as you need to keep the whole file in memory. Either use cURL or fopen, both are simple. Ask if you need more help with either.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, fopen doesnt work either (for regular english, works fine). It's something to do with the url/characters.. perhaps google redirects to the actual characters.. if you enter the sample link I gave int he question, it spells out te`le`phone (which doesnt actually work as a real url.. right?)

Comment: I wonder whether it's something with decoding the URL. Experiment with a decoded version maybe the stream wrapper URL encodes?

Comment: Perhaps this is the problem: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html